# How do I call method from CodeFile using Bootstrap (C#, VS 2013)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm using VS 2013 to develop an aspx page with a C# CodeFile.  If I've used Bootstrap on the aspx page how do I reference the CodeFile to call a function.  On a button click, for example.  This gets handled by a Button1_Click function in the CodeFile:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

But how can I do the same using a Bootstrap button?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="Button1">Button1</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this this as the callback requires a server-side control. If your goal is to style you `<asp:Button>` control, you can set the `CssClass` property to "btn btn-default" like in your HTML.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
```

In you Page or Control definition, you will also need to set the class that contains your `Button1_Click` method as the `Inherits` property.

Comment: It's not possible even though the whole form is contained as such?

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

Comment: Correct. That content control simply controls the placement of this partial page within the MasterPage that the page is designated to use. The master page is also specified in the Page/Control's header.